# How to iterate over ResultSet by using MySql Stored Procedure with "select" keyword?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, resultset, callable-statement

here is my Java method:

```
public static List<Company> selectCompanies() {

    List<Company> companies=new ArrayList<Company>();
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java?user=root&password=root";
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        cs = conn.prepareCall("{call select_companies()}");
        ResultSet rs=cs.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Company company=new Company();
            company.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            company.setName(rs.getString(2));
            companies.add(company);         }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            cs.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return companies;

}
```

Here is stored procedure on MySql db:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE select_companies ()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE o_id SMALLINT;
    DECLARE o_name VARCHAR(52);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,NAME FROM b_company;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO o_id, o_name;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
```

When i try to run the java code i keep getting "resultset is from UPDATE.No data" exception. I am new to stored procedures and i cant figure out what i am missing here.

Comment: The problem is not in Java side, is in your MySQL stored procedure. You're never returning the cursor nor the result set from it to the external world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Luiggi* well mentioned you need to return the results , in your case i assume its `o_id` and `o_name` :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_companies ()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE o_id SMALLINT;
    DECLARE o_name VARCHAR(52);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,NAME FROM b_company;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO o_id, o_name;
    SELECT  o_id, o_name;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
```